# Ensure program runned via Runtime.exec() will die together with the java app

Tags: java, process, runtime

in my java program I am calling external program via `Runtime.exec` and calling `Process.waitFor` to wait for its completion. This is some long-running script. I want to ensure that if anything goes wrong with my java app (e.g. gets killed from outside for example, which btw. really happens from time to time in my case) the external running script will die as well.

I had a look on the `Runtime.addShutdownHook` which might be appropriate for this, but it clearly states that for example on `SIGKILL` no guarantee can be made whether the shutdownhook will or won't run.

Is there any other way how to ensure an external program runned from Java will die together with the calling java process?

Thanks

Comment: I might be completely off here as I am not sure it can be done, but I am adding a comment to contribute with an idea: from your application create and run a simple script (bash for instance) which launches the other (time-consuming) script and from your bash script you can loop and check if the java app is alive.

Comment: I will probably end up doing something like this

Comment: good luck, and may I encourage you to come back and leave a comment about how you sorted it out. I think it's a pretty cool problem, would like to see how it can be solved practically... :)

Comment: I will maybe even put some bounty on it :)

Answer (score 1):

If "Runtime.addShutdownHook" is not sufficien I think from the java side you are out of luck. Some ideas:

1. your script can test if the java app is still running and terminating if needed
2. let your java app update a file with a timestamp and let your script check periodically if the timestamp is to old (and terminate)
3. **Edit:** launch another process which only monitors the java app and the script and kills the script is the java app is gone (of course if THIS process is killed you are out of luck again)

Comment: I am afraid the processing script is something I can't touch really. It looked to me I am out of luck as well but couldn't believe it is that simple :)

Comment: When a problem is too hard, the answer is simple - *"Its too hard"*.  :-)

Comment: Thanks guys, +1 sofar will accept it if nothing better appears in an hour or some.